# Time statistics and verbosity of Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford CoreNLP to make some annotations (I also added some custom annotator) and I'd like to measure how much time each annotator takes. Is there a way to do so easily?

In addition, I noticed that in the source code of the annotator there is a boolean variable `verbose`, but I cannot understand how to set it. Is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StanfordCoreNLP` has a method `String timingInformation()` which will return information on how much time is being used by each annotator.

(This is unrelated to any extra printing that may be controlled by verbose, but you can often set verbose flags for individual annotators although not quite consistently. Thing like: `-parse.debug` or `-pos.verbose` on the command line, or the corresponding things in a properties file.